# Appending a modified list into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, append

I have a list `a`, I append it into a list `l`, then I modify list `a`, and I append it again into `l`.

My code is:

```
a = []
l = []
a.append(1)
l.append(a)

a.append(2)
l.append(a)
```

However, `l` now is = `[[1,2],[1,2]]`, while I want `l` to be `[[1], [1,2]]`.

I solved by modifying my code as follows:

```
a = []
l = []
a.append(1)
l.append(list(a))

a.append(2)
l.append(list(a))
```

My question is: why the operation of appending a modified list `a` into a list `l` that already contains `a` modifies even previously item in `l` appended as `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because lists in python are mutable objects. This means that when you assign a list to a variable you are passing a "reference" to that list (like `c` pointers).

Comment: Thanks, so how to maintain the value at time `i` for a list that changes at time `i+1`? Is my solution right?